# How to fadeIn the globalCaption when item becomes active?

Tags: jquery, javascript, image-gallery

Am using Contentflow to display an image gallery. Among the configuration options there is also this code:

```
        /*
         * called when an item becomes active.
         */
        onMakeActive: function (item) {},
```

On the HTML markup, there is this div:

```
<div class='globalCaption'></div>
```

I want the .globalCaption to fadeIn when item becomes active so I added this:

```
         /*
         * called when an item becomes active.
         */
        onMakeActive: function (item) {
        $(".globalCaption p").fadeIn('fast');
        },
```

...and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

First, change your selector from `$(".globalCaption p")` to `$(".globalCaption")`

Secondly, make sure `.globalCaption` is styled `display:none;` by default. It can not fade in if it is already visible.

Comment: I have tried the display:none; as I didn't have it before and it didn't work. I use refinerycms and the caption is produced as `<p>caption_text</p>` that's why is needed...

Answer (score 0):

You say you have the following div:

```
<div class='globalCaption'></div>
```

But your jQuery code is telling the browser to fade in a `p` element inside that div, and the `p` doesn't seem to exist. Try removing the `p` from the selector, like so:

```
$(".globalCaption").fadeIn('fast');
```

Comment: hey thanks for the input, but the caption text is of the form `<p>caption_text</p>`. this is how it is output in between the divs..

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug with IE and this event 
http://code.google.com/p/contentflow/issues/detail?id=17